# Using a returned string to call a method?

Tags: java, string, arraylist

I have an ArrayList and wish to be able to call an index and use the returned string for a method call.

e.g.

```
stringList.get(2)();
```

Is there any way I could go about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of call you can't call a method in java without an object to call it on.  Is that in the list also.

It would be better to have a list of Runnable...

```
List<Runnable> runnables = ...
runnables.get(2).call();
```

If you have the object you need to call, and you want to use reflection (can be slow) then commons-beans can help make it simple.  See http://commons.apache.org/beanutils

```
import org.apache.commons.beanutils.MethodUtils;

Object target = ...
List<String> methodNames = ...
MethodUtils.invokeMethod(target, methodNames.get(2), /*args*/ null);
```

To give better I'd advice I'd need to know more about the problem you are trying to solve.

Answer (score 11):

So you want the returned String to be used as the name of the method to call?

You can do that using [reflection](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/reflect/), but I'd strongly discourage this.

Instead you will want to look into implementing a [strategy pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern) for example.

Answer (score 2):

**Yes**, there is a way to use the returned string from the list for a method call.

As others users already pointed out, **you need to use [Reflection API](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/reflect/index.html)**. Can be complicated deal with that, depends on the particular scenario you are facing.

Just to show you the basic approach in a concrete but **simplified example**, I create this code. Copy it and play changing the index, and creating new methods with parameters after learn the basics of the API.

```
import java.lang.reflect.*;
import java.util.*;

public class DemoReflection {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        List<String> myStringList = new ArrayList<String>();
        myStringList.add(0, "foo");
        myStringList.add(1, "printStr");
        myStringList.add(2, "otherMethod");
        myStringList.add(3, "stackoverflow");

        int index = 3;
        String methodName = myStringList.get(index);

        try {
            Class<?> c = Class.forName("DemoReflection");
            Object obj = c.newInstance();

            Method method = c.getDeclaredMethod(methodName, null);
            method.invoke(obj, null);

        } catch (SecurityException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InstantiationException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

      }

    public void stackoverflow() {
         System.out.println("Stackoverflow rules!");
    }

    public void printStr() {
         System.out.println("Method printStr invoked...");
    }

}
```

Comment: This code is fragile and cannot be easily refactored (e.g. if you change the name of e.g. otherMethod()).

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of that. Is just to show a simplified way of doing what @Mac asked. I choose to answer his question and write a small sample of code so he can copy and run it immediately to learn more. Everyone is telling him (only based on "stringList.get(2)();") that he shouldn't use that approach and suggesting patterns and plenty of options to redesign his solution. The fact is we don't know the context of his problem, and only a few of us answered his simple question: "Is there any way I can use the returned string from a list for a method call?"

Answer (score 1):

One would have to use reflection.  See http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-reflection/methods.html.

Comment: or a switch, if the amount of available options is known and sort of limited

Answer (score 1):

Does the ArrayList *have* to contain Strings?
Otherwise you could populate it with java.lang.reflect.Method instances, and call Method.invoke() on the returned instance.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your needs, here is an example based on an interface; the list then contains implementations of the interface rather than method names:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        List<Action> actions = new ArrayList<Action>();
        actions.add(new Action(){
            public void execute() {
                System.out.println("Action 0");
            }});
        actions.add(new Action(){
            public void execute() {
                System.out.println("Action 1");
            }});

        actions.get(0).execute();
        actions.get(1).execute();

    }


    static interface Action{ 
        void execute(); 
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Or maybe polymorphism and a factory method would be a better idea.  You'd have to circumscribe the methods you'll be able to call, but that wouldn't be a bad idea.

If you want the full Monty, and you're using Java 6, maybe you can create a JavaScript function object and invoke it with Rhino.

Answer (score 0):

Or if you insist on making the idea work regardless of any obstacles, you could call out to a dynamic language like JRuby or Clojure, both of which are willing to `eval()` a String.

Or Jython or Groovy or...

Answer (score 0):

In Java - no way. That's not a Java language feature. Your're hoping for something like

```
// NOT VALID JAVA
String myColoring = paintBlackOrWhite() ? "black" : "white";
myColoring(myBathroomWall);
// NOT VALID JAVA
```

Like others suggested, a pure technical solution would be using reflections: take the result string, find the corresponding method and invoke it. A technical solution could even be a map like

```
Map<String, java.lang.reflect.Method> myMethods;
```

and do something like

```
get("black").invoke(myObject, myParams);
```

but all of that is nice to know and you shouldn't use it unless forced or you have a concrete problem where even SO doesn't have a solution ;)